# Unity fails to load generic type definition via xml configuration

Tags: c#, xml, generics, unity-container

I'm running into some problems configuring Unity 3.0 via XML configuration. Resolving the generic type will give me the following exception message:

> The type INLog`1 does not have an accessible constructor.

Here's the layout for my logging classes:

```
namespace Common.Utils.Logging {
    public interface INLog
    {
    }

    public interface INLog<T> : INLog where T : class
    {
    }

    public class NLog : INLog
    {
        public NLog(Type type)
        {
        }
    }

    public class NLog<T> : NLog, INLog<T>
        where T : class
    {
        public NLog()
            : base(typeof(T))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I register the generic type with this XML code:

```
<type type="Common.Utils.Logging.INLog[], Common.Utils" mapTo="Common.Utils.Logging.NLog[], Common.Utils" />
```

Loading this configuration gives me the following container registration:

> ```
> LifetimeManager: {Microsoft.Practices.Unity.TransientLifetimeManager}
> LifetimeManagerType: {Name = "TransientLifetimeManager" FullName = "Microsoft.Practices.Unity.TransientLifetimeManager"}
> MappedToType: {Name = "NLog[]" FullName = "Common.Utils.Logging.NLog[]"}
> Name: null
> RegisteredType: {Name = "INLog[]" FullName = "Common.Utils.Logging.INLog[]"}
> ```

Instead of the registration I'm expecting, namely:

> ```
> LifetimeManager: null
> LifetimeManagerType: {Name = "TransientLifetimeManager" FullName = "Microsoft.Practices.Unity.TransientLifetimeManager"}
> MappedToType: {Name = "NLog`1" FullName = "Common.Utils.Logging.NLog`1"}
> Name: null
> RegisteredType: {Name = "INLog`1" FullName = "Common.Utils.Logging.INLog`1"}
> ```

Registering in code works just fine and gives the expected registration:

```
using (IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer())
{
    container.RegisterType(typeof(INLog<>), typeof(NLog<>));
}
```

But I can't manage to get it loaded correctly via the configuration file.
I guess this has to to with the inheritance of the non-generic types (I)NLog...

Does anyone of you guys know how to fix this?

Best regards,
Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of the `[]` notation

```
<type type="Common.Utils.Logging.INLog`1, Common.Utils" mapTo="Common.Utils.Logging.NLog`1, Common.Utils" />
```

Feels awkward, I know, but it should work.