# configure Unity (3.x) for Generic Repository Pattern on WCF project in app.config

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, generics, unity-container

I have a problem to config unity in `app.config` file, My project is wcf service project and I have used unity on this project well, but I don't know exactly, *how to config generic types in app.config*, before that I config my unity for MVC web application in `UnityConfig.cs` class like below and I wanna do that in wcf service project.

What is my wrong?

Works fine in class level:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof (IRepositoryAsync<>), typeof (Repository<>), new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType(typeof (IRepository<>), typeof (Repository<>), new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

Not work in app.config:

```
  <register type="IRepository[], FaraGostar.Repository.Pattern.Repositories" mapTo="Repository, FaraGostar.Repository.Pattern">
        <lifetime type="singleton" />
      </register>
  <register type="IRepositoryAsync[], FaraGostar.Repository.Pattern.Repositories" mapTo="Repository, FaraGostar.Repository.Pattern">
        <lifetime type="singleton" />
      </register>
```

In my personal view I think, I can not config well []!

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766650/unity-fails-to-load-generic-type-definition-via-xml-configuration

Answer (score 0):

See the Generic Types section at the bottom of Unity's [Specifying Types in the Configuration File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660933(v=pandp.20).aspx)

Short answer the unexpected:

```
<register type="IRepository`1, FaraGostar.Repository.Pattern.Repositories" mapTo="Repository`1, FaraGostar.Repository.Pattern">
```